# Run-time error '-2147024773 (8007007b) Document not saved

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

Could anyone pls help regarding below, i am unable to save as pdf

```
AF26 (=TEXT("1st half"&AE36,)
```

[image]

```
sub hihihi()

 Dim fName As String
    
    fName = Range("AF26").Value
    

 
  Range("A1:Q22").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            "C:\Users\user\Google 雲端硬碟 (staff01.phc@gmail.com)\xxx\fax\" & fName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
             
                      

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the value of `fName` in case of the error? And does the path `C:\Users\user\Google 雲端硬碟 (staff01.phc@gmail.com)\xxx\fax\` exist? If it does not exist create the folders first.

Comment: You can test the validity of the path before the export: `If Dir("C:\Users\user\Google 雲端硬碟 (staff01.phc@gmail.com)\xxx\fax\", vbDirectory) <> "" Then`. Don't forget the 'closing' `End If`. You would also rather write the path to a variable, e.g. `FolderPath` (`As String`). The same error will occur if the folder path is valid but the cell is empty or contains `=""` or `'` i.e. its length is 0.